# Loop through the same query to build historical table changing one variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read only access to SQL Server 2008 and I need to build a historical table of percentages based on different points of time in the past (i.e. the last 15 months).  The only value that needs to be changed is on the *** line is -0 after `GETDATE()`). The value needs to change -0, -1, -2...-15. I am inserting into a temp table. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
declare @enddate datetime
declare @end1195 datetime
declare @beg1195 datetime
declare @enddos datetime
declare @begdos datetime
declare @period nvarchar(7)

***set @enddate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-0, -1)  
set @end1195 = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, (@enddate))-1, -1) 
set @beg1195 = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dateadd(month, -6, @enddate)), 0)  
set @enddos = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, (@enddate))-0, -1)  
set @begdos= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dateadd(month, -0, @enddate)), 0)
set @period = cast(MONTH(@enddate) as nvarchar(2)) + '-' + cast(YEAR(@enddate) as nvarchar(4)) 

--1195 BY Facilityid excluding ANES
insert into  ##Fac1195
    select 
        A.Facilityid, cast(1 as int) as Facility,  
        A.FSC_DESC, @period as Period, @begdos as DOS_Beg, 
        @enddos as DOS_End,
        ROUND(sum(A.adjustments)/sum(A.charges), 2) as [1195]  
    from
        (select 
             v.Facilityid, v.localfacility, v.VisitID, v.AccountNumber, 
             v.DOS, FSC.PrimayPayer  as PayerName, 
             FSC.PrimaryCorpFSC as FSC_DESC,
             chg.charges, isnull(adj.Adjustments,0) as Adjustments
             ........
```

Comment: You can first generate required dates using CTE and store in the temporary table. After that you can use that table in the query.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the best way for me to achieve building the historical table without having  manually change the value on line *** -0 after the Getdate() to -1 let query run and complete and then change to -2 and so on?

Comment: Why don't you put your whole query including the variable initialization in a loop and decrement your value?

Comment: Gil R. That worked perfectly. Thanks